# How can I make Celery use pypy as its interpreter?

Tags: python, celery, pypy

I've just installed pypy on my system (Ubuntu 14.04, pypy installed from official PPA).  My default interpreter is still CPython 2.7 (latest), so executing any `celery` commands will run under this default.

How can I specify that Celery should be run under pypy?

Comment: I think you can just change celery's shebang to point stricktly to pypy

Comment: Install celery using PyPy pip. Create a virtualenv first, then activate it. [PyPy is compatible with celery](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/compatibility/wiki/Home#!celery-celery)

Comment: @Cassum, Something like `#!/usr/bin/env pypy`?  Also, how might I check that the proper interpreter is being used?

Comment: @blz Yes, like this. Or use Peter's solution - it's much more cleaner, but not system-wide.
To check interpreter - there are a lot of ways. First that comes into my head (but probably not the easiest one) - check sys.version.

Comment: @PeterWood, do you have any documentation for installing and using pypy pip?  I'm already somewhat familiar with virtualenvs, but I've always just used the built-in pip ...

Comment: Well, you can say `pypy -m pip install virtualenv`, then `pypy -m virtualenv blz_env` to make your environment. Then `blz_env\Scripts\activate`, to activate the environment. It will then show you that you are using that environment. You can safely call `pip install celery` without having to say `pypy -m pip`, and it will install celery to the `blz_env` copy of PyPy.

Comment: @PeterWood, wonderful, thank you very much!  Please feel free to formulate this as an answer and I'll gladly accept it!